# How to send .apk file over mobile Gmail?

Tags: gmail, apk, 8.0-oreo, motorola-moto-z2-play

Since .apk is a regular executable file, I was more than sure that I will be able to trick mobile Gmail in the same way as I was able to trick PC version of Gmail years ago to force it to send a PC executable (.exe) which it prevented as well. Turned out, I was wrong.

Usually changing file extension to `.dat` or some other or compressing it with password (encrypting  file) was enough for PC version of Gmail.

However, for mobile version, everything that I have ready at a hand and tried failed as well:

- sending as plain file (obviously),
- changing `.apk` extension to `.dat` or some other,
- compressing with ZIP with no password,
- compressing with ZIP (ultra compression) and encrypting archive with a password,
- compressing with 7ZIP (ultra compression) and encrypting archive with a password,
- using an [7 years old idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure#comment55859_35818) of double compression:

  - compress `.apk` file into `.zip` file without password,
  - compress resulting `.zip` file again into another `.zip` file with password / encryption.

If mobile Gmail is able to detect that I am sending `.apk` executable file even in 7zip compressed file with password (or it can prevent me from sending such file for any other reasons) do I have any option left? Is there any way to send `.apk` file over mobile Gmail (attach them to message composed in mobile Gmail)?

Comment: If you pack it with 7zip and enable filename encryption everybody need to know the password to read anything from the created archive. Please note that your question is off-topic here as it can be shortened to __"How do I send any data via GMail in a way that it can not be read by Google"__.

Comment: Are other methods acceptable? Most of us just upload the APK to Google Drive, use the Share link, and state it on Gmail...

Comment: Try GPG encryption.

Comment: @Robert I totally agree with you (on both solution and the fact that it makes my question off-topic), so I'll most likely VTC my own question as well. However, to clarify. Not every 7zip client offers this option. The one that I am currently using (Solid Explorer 2) does not. It only password-protects 7zip archives but does not use filename encryption and so, such files fails on Gmail.

Comment: @AndrewT. This is the thing that irritates me the most in the whole picture. I cannot send certain files, because Google prevents me from doing so, because it knows better than me that they can be harmful. In the same time it allows me to upload such file to Google Drive and share a link to it. Either I am missing some key point here or this is totally wrong. This only changes channel (from delivering potentially harmful payload via attachement to a link), but the security concerns remains.

Comment: @IrfanLatif as in answer to Robert -- my file and folder browser does not offer such option. The same as encoding payload as base64 etc. Compressing files (with or without password, but without filename encryption) with 7zip or zip are the only options that Solid Explorer 2 offers.

Comment: @trejder sir blocking `.apk` files and encrypted archives as email attachments is clearly mentioned in GMail policy: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590. No one here can help you with that. Better ask Google. What I suggested is definitely going to work (if email attachment is the only option you want to go with). It's because GPG encryption is very common in emails. Don't limit your options. Some explorer app can't be the ultimate solution to all of your problems. You may look for something else. E.g. use Termux or OpenKeychain for GPG/PGP encryption. Both are open-source and free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking `.apk` files and encrypted archives as email attachments is clearly mentioned in GMail policy:

> To protect you against potential viruses and harmful software, Gmail doesn't allow you to attach certain types of files, including:
> ...
>
> - Password protected archives whose content is an archive

> To protect your account, Gmail doesn't allow you to attach certain types of files...:
> .ade, .adp, .apk, ...

So no one can help with that except Google. You can go with file sharing as suggested by others here, and Google as well:

> If you're sure the file is safe, you can ask the sender to upload the file to Google Drive. Then send it as a Drive attachment.

Source: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590

But if email attachment is the only option you want to go with, use [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard)/[PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#OpenPGP) encryption which is very commonly used in emails, even to encrypt whole emails including subject and body. Many e-mail clients provide OpenPGP-compliant email security. On Android you can use Termux or OpenKeychain for GPG file encryption. Both are open-source and free (I've no affiliation with either).